# Prove $\left|\int_a^b \phi(t) \ dt \right|\le \int_a^b |\phi(t)| \ dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\phi(t) = \phi_1(t)+i\phi_2(t)$ be a complex function in a real interval $t$

In order to prove:
$$\left|\int_a^b \phi(t) \ dt \right|\le \int_a^b |\phi(t)| \ dt$$

I tried:
$$\int_a^b \phi(t) \ dt  = \int_a^b \phi_1(t) + i\phi_2(t) \ dt  = \int_a^b \phi_1(t) \ dt + \int_a^b \phi_2(t) \ dt \rightarrow$$

$$\left|\int_a^b \phi(t) \ dt \right| = \sqrt{\left(\int_a^b \phi_1(t) \ dt\right)^2+\left(\int_a^b \phi_2(t) \ dt\right)^2}\le \sqrt{\left(\int_a^b \phi_1(t) \ dt\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(\int_a^b \phi_2(t) \ dt\right)^2} = $$

$$\left|\int_a^b \phi_1(t) \ dt\right|+\left|\int_a^b \phi_2(t) \ dt\right|\le \int_ a^b |\phi_1(t)| \ dt + \int_a^b |\phi_2(t)| \ dt = \int_a^b |\phi_1(t)|+|\phi_2(t)| \ dt$$

But how to arrive at $\int_a^b |\phi(t)| \ dt$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathcal{P}=\{ a=t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < \cdots < t_n = b \}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ with intermediate points $t_k^* \in [t_{k-1},t_{k}]$, then
$$
       \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\phi(t_k^*)\Delta t_k\right| \le \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\phi(t_k^*)\Delta t_k
$$
leads to the desired result for Riemann integrals after letting $\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0$:
$$
          \left|\int_{a}^{b}\phi(t)dt\right| \le \int_{a}^{b}|\phi(t)|dt.
$$
It's not hard to bootstrap to Lebesgue integrals from there.

Answer (score 11):

There is a trick to this: Let $I=\int \phi \; dt$ and if non-zero use linearity of integral to get:
$$ |I|=\frac{\overline{I}}{|I|}\int \phi \; dt = \mbox{Re} \left( \frac{\overline{I}}{|I|}\int \phi \; dt\right) =  \int \mbox{Re} \left( \frac{\overline{I}}{|I|}\phi\right)  \; dt \leq \int \left| \frac{\overline{I}}{|I|}\phi\right|  \; dt = \int |\phi| dt $$

Comment: You can interpret this in a less arcane way, perhaps, by proving it for a general vector-valued function $\phi$. If you let $C = \int_a^b\phi(t)dt$, then consider $|C|^2 = \int_a^b C\cdot\phi(t)dt$, and use Cauchy-Schwarz.